# How to loop an App().run() function without using recursion with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Imagine I have two buttons, if I press `button1` I earn a point and if I press `button2` I lose a point. When I reach 10 points, the game stops. The way I have been doing it right now calls the `GameApp().run()` every time I click a button to "re-launch" the interface, however if I do it too many times I get a `RecursionError`. I tried doing it with a `while` loop but the interface never launches.

Note: this is a simplified version of my program, it has to be done this way (essentially the number of button changes everytime a button is pressed, so the layout updates accordingly, that's why I call `GameApp().run()` over and over).

```
n = 0

class Game(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InterfacesGame, self).__init__()

        global n
        self.rows = 2

        if n < 10:

            button1 = Button(text="1")
            button2 = Button(text="2")

            button1.bind(on_press = self.add)
            button2.bind(on_press = self.substract)
            self.add_widget(button1)
            self.add_widget(button2)
    

    
    def add(self):
        global n
        n += 1
        GameApp().run()

    def substract(self):
        global n
        n -= 1
        GameApp().run()

class GameApp(App):
    
        def build(self):
            return Game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        GameApp().run()
```

So eventually if I do too many clicks without reaching n = 10, I naturally get a

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded calling class app
```

error.

I tried doing this:

```
n = 0

class Game(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InterfacesGame, self).__init__()

        global n
        self.rows = 2

        while n < 10:

            button1 = Button(text="1")
            button2 = Button(text="2")

            button1.bind(on_press = self.add)
            button2.bind(on_press = self.substract)
            self.add_widget(button1)
            self.add_widget(button2)
    

    
    def add(self):
        global n
        n += 1

    def substract(self):
        global n
        n -= 1

class GameApp(App):
    
        def build(self):
            return Game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        GameApp().run()
```

But the GUI doesn't run (it keeps loading and loading).

Comment: You need to hook the methods in an instance of your game class to the UI, and in those methods, you update the game state. Calling game run recursively is definitely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please? In my full code, each time a button is pressed, the game state changes and the UI updates accordingly but calling game run. How would I go about "looping" the game without doing so ?

Comment: When you call the method `run` the application enters the mainloop (within a `while` loop). Now if you call run (without stopping it ever) in its life cycle then you are creating like, an infinite loop inside another infinite loop. With repeated calls of run which eventually reaches max recursion limit - that's not intended. Better, you should handle your process (gaining or loosing points etc.) within a method.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I have tried using a Clock but I cannot get it to work. I have now built everything under `def build(self):` instead in the `GameApp(App)` instead of the `Game(GridLayout)` class but I'm still stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by '*When I reach 10 points, the game stops*', exit the application completely or discontinue the button actions or something else ? Please describe it in detail.

Comment: When 10 points are reached, the layout is remplaced by a single button with the text "You won!", and when clicking on it, the game starts all over again (with n = 0).

Comment: Did you try with multiple `Screen`s with `ScreenManager` ? I think using screen has more advantages for this purpose.

Comment: I am trying that but seem to run into the same problem. Essentially, I have a `Screen` and each time a button is pressed, a new `Screen` is created and switch to it. However, I cannot seem to "update" the UI with it as I can't loop back to the beginning of my `build` method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and your following comment :

> When 10 points are reached, the layout is remplaced by a single button with the text "You won!", and when clicking on it, the game starts all over again (with n = 0).

I implemented a complete example using `Screen`s and `ScreenManager`.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = ("""

ScreenManager:
    id: sm

    Screen:
        name: "First Screen"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Button:
                text: "1"
                on_release: app.add_point()

            Button:
                text: "2"
                on_release: app.subtract_point()

    Screen:
        name: "Second Screen"

        Label:
            text: "You Won"
            font_size: "40sp"

        Button:
            text: "Play again"
            size_hint: 0.75, None
            height: "50dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.25}
            on_release: sm.current = "First Screen"

""")


class GameApp(App):
    count = 0

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.root

    def add_point(self):
        if self.count < 10:
            self.count += 1
        else:
            self.root.current = "Second Screen"
            self.count = 0 # Reset counter.

    def subtract_point(self):
        if 0 < self.count: # Assuming only positive values.
            self.count -= 1



GameApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the full answer. Using screens works great for this mini scenario, however in my real scenario the number of buttons changes randomly each time the game is over when n = 10. So perhaps screen is not best suited for this.

Comment: What do you mean by '*the number of buttons changes randomly each time...*' ?